# Insert an image after every x words using jQuery

Tags: jquery, text

I'm trying to do this using text with jQuery:

[image: Example]

I need to have an array and add images from it in a balise p each x words. (x is a random number).

With jQuery it's easy to count words:

```
var count = $("#example1").text().replace(/ /g,'').length;
```

How can I randomly add images into the text?

Comment: u can paste u r array in http://jsfiddle.net/ . which word u need to replace to image?

Comment: I don't want to replace but add an image after X word.
I want to inject in my text some images from an array

Comment: u can show u r array. can u give me one example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the whole html(the one with only text) by the new html, which includes images:

html:

```
<div>one two three</div>
```

js:

```
var wordList = $("div").html().split(' ');
var newHtml = '';

$.each(wordList, function(index, word){
  newHtml += ' ' + word;
  if (index == 1) {
    newHtml += '<img src="http://www.newarkadvertiser.co.uk/weather/icons/white-cloud.gif" />'     
  }        
});
$('div').html(newHtml)
```

example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snies/DN7F8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

DEMO:

http://jsbin.com/ajowib/2/ - Looping image array, sequence 3, offset 2

http://jsbin.com/ajowib/ - Not looping, sequence 5, offset 3

HTML:

```
<div id="myText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"], // Array to contains image url's
        sequence = 5, // The sequence of witch the images is inserted
        sequenceOffset = 3, // The offset from the start
        loopImages = true, // If you want to loop throw your image array again and again            

        text = $("#myText").html().split(" "),
        newText = [],
        i = 0, y = 0,
        len = text.length;

    for( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        if ( (i % sequence) === sequenceOffset ) {
            if ( loopImages || y < images.length ) {
                newText.push("<img src='" + images[y%images.length] + "'/>");
                y++;
            }
        }
        newText.push(text[i]);
    }

    $("#myText").html(newText.join(" "));
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for me - and I was able to split text into columns, PLUS add content into a slider for very bulky text. Thanks! I will provide full code once done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnImage').on('click', function () {
                var imageText = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
                var imageArraySrc = ['http://www.newarkadvertiser.co.uk/weather/icons/white-cloud.gif', 'http://www.newarkadvertiser.co.uk/weather/icons/white-cloud.gif', 'http://www.newarkadvertiser.co.uk/weather/icons/white-cloud.gif'];
                var text = $('div#example1').text();

                $.each(imageText, function (i, value) {
                    text = text.replace(new RegExp(value, 'g'), value + ' <img src="' + imageArraySrc[i] + '" />');
                });

                $('div#example1').html(text);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example1">
        one there two are is an image in this text . one two three.
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnImage" value="Click Me!" />
</body>
</html>
```